# Loading a pdf in pdf viewer syncfusion

Tags: jquery, pdf, syncfusion

I have a the following code in my cshtml:

```
<span id = "/C/documents/demo.pdf" class="viewDoc">Demo.pdf</span>
```

Upon clicking on the document name, it hits the function viewDoc, below:

```
function viewDoc(docPath){
$.ajax({
    url: "/ViewDoc/LoadPDF",
    dataType: "text",
    type: "POST",
    data: docPath,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     $("#divViewer").ejPdfViewer({
            serviceUrl: “https://js.syncfusion.com/ejServices/api/PdfViewer”, 
            documentLoad: "load"
        });
         var divViewer= $("#divViewer").data("ejPdfViewer");
         obj.load(data["data"]);
    },
  });
}
```

My LoadPDF action in the controller is as below:

```
public Json LoadPDF (string docPath){
   PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(docPath);
   MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   loadedDocument .Save(memoryStream);
   var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
   return JSON {new (Convert.ToBase64String(bytes))};  
}
```

However, when the doc is being loaded in the syncfusion pdf viewer, it is displaying an empty PDF.

When I am converting a Microsoft Word to PDF using syncfusion then converting it to base64 string and sending the string to the PDF viewer, it is loading ok.

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?  OR is there anyway to load the pdf to the pdf viewer without converting it to base64 string?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have analyzed the code snippet and we suspect that the issue is due to loading the base64 string directly in to the load method of the PDF Viewer control, kindly refer the modified code snippet for loading the document in to the PDF Viewer control.

```
function viewDoc(docPath){
 $.ajax({
url: "/ViewDoc/LoadPDF",
dataType: "text",
type: "POST",
data: docPath,
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
 $("#divViewer").ejPdfViewer({
        serviceUrl: “https://js.syncfusion.com/ejServices/api/PdfViewer”, 
        documentLoad: "load"
    });
     var divViewer= $("#divViewer").data("ejPdfViewer");
     **divViewer.load("data:application/pdf;base64," + data["data"]);**  //kindly load the document as pdf.
},
 });
   }
```

Note: If the above solution doesn’t resolve your issue. So kindly provide us the sample and PDF document in which you have faced the issue so that would be helpful for us to analysis more and assist you better.

Comment: Ok I will try the solution given and will let you know.   However I would like to know if there is another, better way of viewing a pdf in the pdf viewer?  Do I necessarily need to convert it to base64 string?  Thank you for your help